# Torsors for 2-groups

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, groupoids

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a 2-group, by which I mean a strict monoidal category in which all objects are invertible (up to coherent isomorphisms) and all morphisms are invertible (strictly).

1. What is the definition of $\mathbb{G}$-torsor, thought of as a groupoid equipped with a $\mathbb{G}$-action?
2. Let $G$ be a group, let $\mathbb{B} G$ be $G$ regarded as a one-object groupoid, and let $\mathbb{A}$ be the automorphism 2-group of $\mathbb{B} G$ (i.e. the 2-group whose objects are the group automorphisms of $G$ and whose morphisms $f_0 \to f_1$ are those elements $g$ in $G$ such that $g f_0 (x) = f_1 (x) g$ for all $x$ in $G$). There is an obvious action of $\mathbb{A}$ on $\mathbb{B} G$. Does it make $\mathbb{B} G$ into an $\mathbb{A}$-torsor?
3. If the answer to (2) is no, then what is the connection with the old notion of "gerbe with band"? My impression is that $\mathbb{B} G$ is supposed to be a gerbe with band $\mathrm{OutAut}(G)$ (over the point).

Comment: The definition at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsor seems to generalize to this case.

Comment: A 2-group is not quite a group object in $\mathbf{Cat}$, though. (Even in the case where objects are strictly invertible, the inversion involves an $(-)^\mathrm{op}$, much like in partially ordered groups.) Moreover, it's not clear to me that this is the right definition; there are pre-existing notions of principal $n$-bundle, making use of classifying spaces for $n$-groups...